# Bootstrap tabbed pane displaying all tabs on load

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pane

my code is displaying all tabs on load.
If I remove "active" from the other tabs, they won't display the graphs in their respective panes. How is this fixable? I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class ="container col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div id="monitor" class="panel panel-default tab-box">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 60px">
         <h3 class="panel-title" style = "margin-bottom: 5px">
            <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
            Steps count
        </h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <!-- Week tab -->
            <li class="active"> <a href="#week-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="line">Week</a></li>
            <!-- Month tab -->
            <li> <a href="#month-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="bar2">Month</a></li>
            <!-- Year -->
            <li> <a href="#year-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="bar3">Year</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="week-tab" class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 10px">

                <div id="week_step-line" class = "graph" ></div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="month-tab" class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 10px">

                <div id="month_step-line" class = "graph" ></div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="year-tab" class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 10px">

                    <div id="year_step-line" class = "graph" ></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added a picture of my problem. My morris chart has too little space if I don't have all the tabs as active.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u25Ad.jpg

Comment: Read this doc http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: You can activate individual tabs by calling show property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine.. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/d083nLvo/6/)**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Steps count
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        
        <div role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#Week" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Week</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#Month" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Month</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#Year" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Year</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Week">1...</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Month">2...</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Year">3...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see your point. The initial graph displays fine. However if the other ones isn't active, they wont display in their pane either. Seeing they don't have any space. If you understand what I mean?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: If want to show first tab always then add this in jquery part $('#myTab li:eq(0) a').tab('show')

Comment: If you have 5 tab then first tab only displayed..if you want see 3rd tab then you have click that tab which will show the content.

Comment: Look at the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tab shown method to trigger you script when the tab is shown. u can either have it global for all tabs or also id specific.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

     // your script

})
```

you can trigger your graph method or if it has any relow mehod u can trigger that. Hope this solution helps you.